# Does such an optimization exist in g++?

Tags: c++, stl, copy-constructor

Consider the following code snippet:

```
list<someClass>& method();
....
list<someClass> test = method();
```

What will the behavior of this be? Will this code:

1. Return a reference to the someClass instance returned by return value optimization from method(), and then perform someClass's copy constructor on the reference?
2. Avoid calling the copy constructor somehow?

Specifically, I have methods that are returning very large lists, and I want to avoid calling copy constructors on each return value.

EDIT: Erm, sorry, code compiles now...

Comment: Huh? That won't even compile. There's no implicit conversion from `std::list<t>` to `t`. If you care about performance, you should be using `vector` or `deque` instead of list anyway.

Comment: As with any question about optimisation, the only real answer is to examine the assembler output for your specific code.

Comment: Did you mean ` method().front()`? You will also have to make sure that the list object to which the returned list reference points to stays alive after the execution of ` method() ` .

Comment: @Billy : since he didn't give the definition of `someClass`, it's impossible to tell if this will compile.  And it's a little presumptuous to know his data structure is suboptimal if you don't know how he's gonna use it :)

Comment: Your third line tries to convert a list of someClass to an object of someClass this wont compile.

Comment: `struct someClass { someClass(std::list<someClass>&); };`?

Comment: @Stephen: Unless you need to splice, there's rarely ever reason to use `std::list` -- even for insertions in the middle, `std::deque` is usually more efficient, making use of both the ideas that make `vector` and `list` efficient and producing a reasonable hybrid. As for the definition of `someType`, I don't see how that's relevant, again, given that there's no conversion from `std::list<T>` to `T`.

Comment: @Billy : I agree that normally, `vector` and `deque` are the obvious choices.  But not always, for example, he may need to splice, or he may be trying to minimize copies. If there's a non-explicit constructor that takes a `std::list<someClass>`, this would work ( here is working code: http://www.mobwrite.net/someclass ). He didn't give us that code, so we don't know.  Now we do know, of course, and you were right, like we all expected... but it was presumptuous :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The copy constructor will have to be called, because this code must make a copy:  the `method()` function returns a reference to some object, a copy of which must be stored in the variable `test`.

Since you are returning a reference and not an object, there is no need for return value optimization.

If you do not want to make a copy of the list, you can make `test` a reference:

```
list<someClass>& test = method();
```

However, `test` will then refer to the original list, so any modifications made to `test` will also be made to the original list, and whenever the original list is destroyed, `test` will become invalid (which means you have to be more careful with object lifetimes).

Answer (score 1):

There exists RVO. I am not sure if it applies here. Anyways it's one way to minimize copying.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't assign a list to someClass (unless you overloaded the assignment operator or copy constructor, and use the returned list to copy construct). If you didn't this shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it is difficult to hazard a guess as to what you are trying to achieve here by returning the reference to a list and then making a copy of it.

Do consider the idea of returning an iterator to the list (or reference to the iterator) if possible (assuming that the list is not something local to a function etc).